# Sqlite3 database Create Table Error

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Well Hello guys, I'm working on an android app with an sqlite3 database, can you please help me to debug this code, because it says syntax error and I can't find the error.

```
"CREATE TABLE cancion(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, genre_id INTEGER, singer_id INTEGER," +
            " FOREING KEY (genre_id) REFERENCES genre(id)," +
            " FOREING KEY (singer_id) REFERENCES singer(id));";
    String queryGenero = "CREATE TABLE genre(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);";
    String querySinger = "CREATE TABLE singer(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);";
```

Comment: in which sequence your queries are fired 
is the queryGenero and querySinger are fired before your firs statement executed?

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo in: `FOREING` should be `FOREIGN`